# Lyft API Cancel Ride not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-status-code-500, lyft-api

Following the documentation from Lyft, I have

```
https://api.lyft.com/v1/rides/<ride_id>/cancel
```

with Authorization and Content-Type Header but the server is constantly returning 500

> internal server error

So authorization passes (Bearer is correct) and Ride Id is returned from the Request Ride Endpoint.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow, the endpoint started working. I'll close this issue.